# Searching for Contacts in the New Google Contacts Layout

Tags: google-contacts

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to search just my contacts in the new layout for [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/). It seems to search everyone but my contacts (unless they have Google+). My initial instinct was just to use the find feature built in to Firefox and Google Chrome, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> only seems search the contacts that are visible on the screen at that point in time. It doesn't work for ones that are hidden below or above. Plus, you actually have to hit it twice because the first time it just moves the cursor to Google's search bar. This is becoming very frustrating... Does anyone know any solutions to this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure I see the issue. I'm using the Contacts Preview with the defaults to their original value, and when I put text in "search for anyone" and search, it only brings back people on my contacts. Are you just looking to view your old "My Contacts" group?

Comment: That's not what it does for me. At the top of the search results it says "Search Google+ for..." and it does **not** display any of my contacts.

Comment: That's...odd. I can't reproduce that.

Comment: Try turning off pulling in G+ circles. Uncheck the box for it under "Settings". (More at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6164066?p=contactcircles under "I don’t want to see my Google+ circles in my contact list")

Comment: @AlE.Thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: That fixed it for me!  Thanks!  Or at least my contacts show up first now.

Answer (score 1):

The screen shot shows near the bottom "All Contacts (176) Includes circles". Click on "Includes circles". This will display the "Settings" dialog. Uncheck the

> Include everyone from your circles in the All contacts list. Excludes
>   circles you just follow. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/mail/?p=contactcircles&hl=en&%20authuser=0)

Then click on Save.

Now when you search for a contact the results will show only contacts from your contacts list.

The autocomplete dropdown option list will still show people from the Google+ directory.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not work (at least not for me). It was already discussed in the comments of the question.

Comment: Please add more details to your question in order to understand better what you are expecting and how you know that the search results are not in your contacts.

Comment: @druciferre: It's possible that the search index is cached with G+ circles data in it. After changing this setting, a day or two later are you still seeing the wrong data?